# Order in stacked barplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame, nothing to fancy about it.

```
df_bar<-data.frame(capacity = c(no[2],no[1]-no[2],max(df_l$load)-no[1]), type = c("Nuclear","Coal","Gas"),a = c("Optimal","Optimal","Optimal"))
```

[image]

I tried to create a stacked barplot via ggplot, but I also need to make sure that I have a specific order in that plot, with N being the closest to the axis and C the furthest. However, the simple code leads to this.

```
ggplot(df_bar, aes(y=capacity, x=a, fill=type)) + 
geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

[image]

How can I maybe alter the code so it respects the order I need?

Answer (score 1):

1.Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

```
df_bar<-data.frame(capacity = c(2,2,2),
                   type = c("Nuclear","Coal","Gas"),
                   a = c("Optimal","Optimal","Optimal"))
```

`ggplot2` respects the order of ordered factors when plotting. We can use that to our advantage:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_bar, aes(y=capacity, x=a, fill=factor(type, levels=c( "Coal", "Gas", "Nuclear")))) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
  labs(fill="type")
```

[image]